# How to run APIDemos on Android emulator?

Tags: android

I would like to run APIDemos under `platforms\android-1.5\samples` directory on Android emulator but I don't know how to do it.
Do I need to generate an apk or import sources as an eclipse project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to import the project sources as an Eclipse project and then run from Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I tried importing the Api Demos and it did not work for me. Try this:
File->New->Android Project->Create Project from Existing Sources , 
select API Demos for the browser window and finish.

It works for me !

Answer (score 0):

No, I see if we run Android Emulator from Eclipse, it's very slow because Eclipse must call Android Emulator (about 5 minute).

Edit: I found a solution here: http://www.androidfreeware.org/tutorials/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android-device-emulator